# python DFS directory and Print out the longest path

Tags: python, directory, depth-first-search, longest-path

I meet some problems here. I can search all the directory and print it out, but I just cannot find the longest path. Here is my terminal stats.

14102
1
1
/home/bob/Desktop

```
import os

def DFS(path, dirCallback = None, fileCallback = None):
    stack = []
    ret = []
    stack.append(path);
    while len(stack) > 0:
        tmp = stack.pop(len(stack) - 1)
        if(os.path.isdir(tmp)):
            ret.append(tmp)
            for item in os.listdir(tmp):
                stack.append(os.path.join(tmp, item))
            if dirCallback:
                dirCallback(tmp)
        elif(os.path.isfile(tmp)):
            ret.append(tmp)
            if fileCallback:
                fileCallback(tmp)
    return ret

def print_directory(path):
    print "dir: " + path

def print_file(path):
    print "file: " + path

d = DFS('~/', print_directory, print_file)

print max([x for x in d ],key=lambda x: x.count("/"))
```

I just have not idea why it cannot print out the longest path here. I am just the new to python and also I am a English learner, if I make any misunderstand, please let me know.

UPDATE: I can find the longest path right now, but I cannot use '~/' to find the directory.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Search.py", line 29, in <module>
    print max([x for x in d ],key=lambda x: x.count("/"))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

this is Error message.

Comment: what os are you using? If using mac of linux try `ls = temp.split('/')`. To find the longest you can also use `print max([x for x in d ],key=lambda x: x.count("/"))`

Comment: OMG, the last one is so useful, thank you for the help. Yeah, I am using the linux, which is centOS.

Comment: so it worked ok? Paths in linux use `/` so `\\\` was splitting nothing

Comment: Yeah I have change my code a lot. But looks like I cannot use ~/ to find my directory. Any solutions?      d = DFS('~/', print_directory, print_file)      It just show the Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Search.py", line 29, in <module>
    print max([x for x in d ],key=lambda x: x.count("/"))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Answer (score 1):

This code should be fully working:

```
import os

def DFS(path, dirCallback = None, fileCallback = None):
    stack = []
    ret = []
    stack.append(path);
    while len(stack) > 0:
        tmp = stack.pop(len(stack) - 1)
        if(os.path.isdir(tmp)):
            ret.append(tmp)
            for item in os.listdir(tmp):
                stack.append(os.path.join(tmp, item))
            if dirCallback:
                dirCallback(tmp)
        elif(os.path.isfile(tmp)):
            ret.append(tmp)
            if fileCallback:
                fileCallback(tmp)
    return ret

def print_directory(path):
    print "dir: " + path

def print_file(path):
    print "file: " + path

home = os.path.expanduser('~')
d = DFS(home, print_directory, print_file)


print max([x for x in d ],key=lambda x: x.count("/"))
```